# How to find Min and Max in Python without using lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completely lost on how to solve this problem. We are to write a program that asks a user for an amount of integers and then calculates the minimum and maximum from the integers the user enters. Below is the assignment:

Write a program that asks the user how many integers they would like to enter. You can assume they will enter an integer >= 1. The program will then prompt the user to enter that many integers. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest of those numbers (no, you cannot use lists, or any other material we haven't covered). When you run your program it should match the following format:

How many integers would you like to enter?
4
Please enter 4 integers.
-4
105
2
-7
min: -7
max: 105

Any help would be extremely appreciated

```
num_1 = int(input("How many integers would you like to enter?")) #enter an 
integer greater than or equal to 1
print("Please enter", num_1, "integers.")
min = 0
max = 0
for i in range(0,num_1):
numbers = int(input()) #reads the integers one at a time
     if numbers > 0 a
       numbers = min
```

Comment: `-7` is not >= `1` I understand that’s besides the point but seems weird that’s the example given the task explanation.

Comment: What do you expect `if numbers > 0 a` to do?

Comment: You should avoid using `min` and `max` as variables in Python as they are builtin functions.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t compare to `0` in the loop. Compare to the actual stored values.

Also setting min and max to the first input and then looping one less time will work as expected. You don’t want hard coded initial values here. You want to compare to the users input itself

```
num_1 = int(input("How many integers would you like to enter?")) #enter an integer greater than or equal to 1
print("Please enter", num_1, "integers.")
_min = int(input())
_max = _min
for i in range(1,num_1):
    number = int(input()) #reads the integers one at a time
    if number > _max:
        _max = number
    if number < _min:
        _min = number
```

Answer (score 0):

For each number:

```
if numbers < min:
    min = numbers
if numbers > max:
    max = numbers
```

Answer (score -1):

```
N = int(input())
smallest = 0
largest = 0
for i in range(N):
   entered_number = int(input())
   if (i == 0): #consider the first number is minimum first
       smallest = entered_number
   if(entered_number < smallest ):
       smallest = entered_number
   if(entered_number > largest):
       largest = entered_number
print (smallest)
print (largest)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).