# Find Min and Max using loops only

Tags: python

My program asks the user to enter the number of integers they want to enter. Then the user enters integer. Then the program outputs the max and min of those integers.

I cannot use lists, only loops and conditional statements are allowed.

I tried setting max and min to specific values:

```
max_num = 0
min_num = 0
print("Please enter the number of integers you want to enter:")
inte_num = int(input())
for val in range (1, inte_sum + 1):
    user_num = int(input())
    if user_num >= max_num:
        max_num = user_num
    elif use_num <= min_num:
        min_num = user_num
print("max:", max_num)
print("min:", min_num)
```

The expected output of `1, 2, 3, 4` is max: 4 and min: 1, but the actual output is max: 4 and min: 0

Comment: Initialize `min = float('inf') and max = -float('inf')`.

Comment: @vb_rises You can initialize `max` as `float('-inf')` instead to save one unary operation.

Comment: @blhsing inf is not allowed

Comment: @proudparrot you can do `min = 9223372036854775807` (max int value) instead of 0.

Comment: This question was already asked [How to find Min and Max in Python without using lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360099/how-to-find-min-and-max-in-python-without-using-lists) and I already provided and answer there

Comment: tested that, it does not give max and min. just lets user enter their desired number of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have initialized `max_num` and `min_num` to `0` at first. In the specific example you gave, `1,2,3,4`, none of the input is smaller than the initial `min_num` value which is `0`, thus `min_num` does not change.

One way to solve this problem is to initialize `max_num` and `min_num` to `None` and put values into `max_num` and `min_num` if they are `None`, as the following:

```
max_num = None
min_num = None
print("Please enter the number of integers you want to enter:")
inte_num = int(input())
for val in range (1, inte_num + 1):
    user_num = int(input())
    if max_num is None or user_num > max_num:
        max_num = user_num
    if min_num is None or user_num < min_num:
        min_num = user_num
print("max:", max_num)
print("min:", min_num)
```

Comment: i got that part. What would be a good way to get the desired output?

Comment: @proudparrot I added a possible solution to my answer above :)

Comment: Noooicee. That passed all my tests. Thanks a bunch. So I can just arbitrarily set something to a boolean value and then compare values. I see now.